# WEB SCRAPING - python requests session not able to gather data

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've seen some similar threads but neither gave me the answer. I simply need to get html content from one website. I'm sending the POST request with data for particular case and then using GET requests I want to **scrape** the text from html. The problem is that I always receive the first page's content. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin':'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl',
    'Referer':'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',

}

data = {
'kodWydzialu':'PT1R', 
'nrKw':'00037314', 
'cyfraK':'9',
}

url = 'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW'

r = requests.session()
r.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
final_content = r.get(url, headers=headers)
print(final_content.text)
```

The GET requests come from ("https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/eukw201906070952/js/jquery-1.11.0_min.js
") but it returns a wall of code. My goal is to **scrape** the page which appears after providing the data from above to search menu.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import json
import urllib.request



headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin':'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl',
    'Referer':'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',

}

data = {
'kodWydzialu':'PT1R',
'nrKw':'00037314',
'cyfraK':'9',
}

url = 'https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW'


r=urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=bytes(json.dumps(data), encoding="utf-8"))
final_content = r
for i in r:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it stil returns the bad content (The beginning screen)

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.